# Slack API - chat.postMessage support for Localization in attachments

Tags: localization, slack, slack-api

I am using `chat.postMessage` with attachments to send a direct message to a Slack User.

In attachment I have a button and I wanted to change label (text) of this button based on the Slack user language preference.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A couple of Slack API methods have an optional locale feature. By calling them with the `include_locale` property set to `true` they will return the locale information.

The locale field is a string containing a [IETF language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag), such as `en-US`, `fr-FR`, `es-ES`, or `de-DE`, and other future values.

Here is a list of Slack API methods supporting the locale feature:

- `channels.info`
- `conversations.info`
- `groups.info`
- `im.info`
- `im.open`
- `rtm.start`
- `users.info`
- `users.list`

So for your case you would first call `users.info` for the user to find out his correct locale and then compose your text accordingly.

Check out this [offical post](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-locale-locale-locale) for full details on locale support by the Slack API.